# How to blit Score on screen in SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been working on a Pong clone game. It's almost done, just when I thought everything is perfect. The SDL_ttf.h Library seems to be a pain.

I am going to give a general overview and not the whole code just to make things simple.
I have used-

```
int PlayerScore=0;
int AIScore=0;
```

Here's the syntax to render text in SDL.

```
SDL_Surface *TTF_RenderText_Solid(TTF_Font *font, const char *text, SDL_Color fg);
```

Now, see that **const char* text**? That's where I need to give my PlayerScore/AIScore there. PlayerScore/AIScore are of integer type but they are supposed to be in const char* type. So after hours of browsing and research I found that there is this **sstream** library I can use to convert integer to *const char**

I declare my surface as imgTxt;

```
SDL_Surface* imgTxt;
std::stringstream strm;
strm << PlayerScore;

...

imgTxt = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, strm.str().c_str(), fColor );
SDL_BlitSurface(imgTxt,NULL,screen,null);
```

Guess what? The conversion is successful. But I faced a different problem, just when I blit the surface. It displays the score as **0000000000000000000000000000** and it keeps on going, after a while the font disappears and nothing happens.
I've no idea why this is happening, maybe the string is being appended with the score in every loop? This is the screenshot.
[image]

Is there any solution to this as to why this is happening? Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the whole code, I cannot say. It certainly looks like it thought.

Are you creating the sstream every loop?

An alternative would be to use sprintf.

```
char buffer [50];
sprintf (buffer, "%d", PlayerScore);
```

and later

```
imgTxt = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, buffer, fColor );
SDL_BlitSurface(imgTxt,NULL,screen,null);
```